# How to detect peaks in a given 1D array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, search, graph

I have array of (y) values. These values ranges and produces a graph like this [**`Graph`**](http://joakimkemeny.github.io/jke.d3.ecg/)

I would like to take that array and get the index of P, Q, R, S and T property.

If you're wondering what those property mean. Check this image to explain which part of the array refers to the property:  [**`P, Q, R, S, T`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRWoV.png).

Suppose we have an array of y values like so:

```js
const Data = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, 0.0000137939453125, 0.000049560546875,
  0.00008740234375, 0.00015966796875, 0.000262451171875, 0.0003975830078125, 0.0005687255859375,
  0.0007802734375, 0.001037353515625, 0.0013468017578125, 0.00172119140625, 0.0021756591796875,
  0.0027232666015625, 0.0033880615234375, 0.004206787109375, 0.0052380371093750005,
  0.006586181640625, 0.008400146484375001, 0.010904296875, 0.0144892578125, 0.0196798095703125,
  0.049684204101562504, 0.0886883544921875, 0.11185363769531251, 0.134164306640625,
  0.137352294921875, 0.1160369873046875, 0.08516308593750001, 0.0539765625,
  0.014997436523437501, -0.015882568359375, -0.0387554931640625, -0.06125732421875, -0.0745780029296875, -0.07479357910156251, -0.0725338134765625, -0.0418538818359375,
  0.08582861328125001, 0.397717529296875, 0.8136408691406251, 1.2295617980957032,
  0.9944150390625001, 0.2824605712890625, -0.38949267578125, -0.597251220703125, -0.425675537109375, -0.1537947998046875, -0.0500914306640625, -0.0111041259765625,
  0.0027451171875, 0.0071739501953125, 0.008443359375, 0.0094327392578125, 0.012530517578125,
  0.0176046142578125, 0.0300162353515625, 0.0433489990234375, 0.056962646484375004,
  0.0704832763671875, 0.0770511474609375, 0.0898175048828125, 0.10311853027343751,
  0.117046142578125, 0.1312630615234375, 0.1529300537109375, 0.167607177734375,
  0.1899068603515625, 0.2124422607421875, 0.235044677734375, 0.2575535888671875,
  0.2724073486328125, 0.286978271484375, 0.3007579345703125, 0.3067425537109375,
  0.3106370849609375, 0.303756103515625, 0.2897236328125, 0.25916931152343753,
  0.2200599365234375, 0.1728209228515625, 0.133416259765625, 0.086224853515625,
  0.05493408203125, 0.02409423828125, 0.00922607421875, -0.0043409423828125, -0.0097349853515625, -0.013127685546875, -0.01423095703125, -0.013834716796875, -0.012556030273437501, -0.010675048828125, -0.00835888671875, -0.0057305908203125, -0.0000562744140625
]
```

Based on the values above, I would like to get indexes of the properties.

We have this framework [**`slayerjs`**](https://github.com/bbc/slayer) which basically detects the peaks. But it only returns the highest peak given an array of points.

Comment: So write code that loops over it and when it goes down, up again, you know you have a peak....

Comment: But sometimes we might have different data points, which means my condition wont be met in most cases @epascarello

Comment: Reduce the number of points to get the peak in the interval of interest

Comment: In most cases we might have 1000 points. I cant work on static array. the data points are produced based on time limit @Juan

Comment: It could be 30 secs, 1 minute or even 10 min

Comment: 1000 points must represent a certain amount of time. Perhaps you can process the 1000 points in smaller sub-segments. The slope should provide a factor know which maximum is the one you are looking for.

Comment: I am curious, if there are three waves in a row, so the middle one will be treated as 'R'? or only when the beg/end of the wave is less than zero?

Comment: @Sphinx yes that is correct. No matter how long the values maybe, the will always have these spikes

Comment: What about finding the maximum values between negative values in the series

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? To achieve what? @Juan

Comment: to get the peak values, isn't that what you want to find by analyzing the series?

Comment: Yes that is correct @Juan

Comment: See the line how after each peak, and before the next one it goes under the line, which is below zero

Comment: Yes I would need to be able to get those, because those represent Q and S @Juan

Comment: The overall max would be R.Following that the min value below zero would be S, When the values change  sign again, the next maximum would be T. After T in the moving graph, the line again goes under zero, when it returns to positive, the next max is P. For the turning points that delimit the segments you can check when the values are zero or change from zero to + or -. I think this would be a way to do it.

Comment: Yes, your correct. And I'm trying to achieve that. @Juan

Comment: I am sorry but then I don't understand which is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My opinion:**

1. calculate out all waves (either up or down) and the index go across y-axis=0.
2. From the result of Step 1, we can calculate out P, Q, R, S.

**For example:** Assuming the result of Step 1 is one array=found.

if `found[index]` is upwave, `found[index-1]` and `found[index+1]` are downwave, then we will know `found[index]` is one Q.

Below are the codes:

```js
const test = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, 0.0000137939453125, 0.000049560546875,
  0.00008740234375, 0.00015966796875, 0.000262451171875, 0.0003975830078125, 0.0005687255859375,
  0.0007802734375, 0.001037353515625, 0.0013468017578125, 0.00172119140625, 0.0021756591796875,
  0.0027232666015625, 0.0033880615234375, 0.004206787109375, 0.0052380371093750005,
  0.006586181640625, 0.008400146484375001, 0.010904296875, 0.0144892578125, 0.0196798095703125,
  0.049684204101562504, 0.0886883544921875, 0.11185363769531251, 0.134164306640625,
  0.137352294921875, 0.1160369873046875, 0.08516308593750001, 0.0539765625,
  0.014997436523437501, -0.015882568359375, -0.0387554931640625, -0.06125732421875, -0.0745780029296875, -0.07479357910156251, -0.0725338134765625, -0.0418538818359375,
  0.08582861328125001, 0.397717529296875, 0.8136408691406251, 1.2295617980957032,
  0.9944150390625001, 0.2824605712890625, -0.38949267578125, -0.597251220703125, -0.425675537109375, -0.1537947998046875, -0.0500914306640625, -0.0111041259765625,
  0.0027451171875, 0.0071739501953125, 0.008443359375, 0.0094327392578125, 0.012530517578125,
  0.0176046142578125, 0.0300162353515625, 0.0433489990234375, 0.056962646484375004,
  0.0704832763671875, 0.0770511474609375, 0.0898175048828125, 0.10311853027343751,
  0.117046142578125, 0.1312630615234375, 0.1529300537109375, 0.167607177734375,
  0.1899068603515625, 0.2124422607421875, 0.235044677734375, 0.2575535888671875,
  0.2724073486328125, 0.286978271484375, 0.3007579345703125, 0.3067425537109375,
  0.3106370849609375, 0.303756103515625, 0.2897236328125, 0.25916931152343753,
  0.2200599365234375, 0.1728209228515625, 0.133416259765625, 0.086224853515625,
  0.05493408203125, 0.02409423828125, 0.00922607421875, -0.0043409423828125, -0.0097349853515625, -0.013127685546875, -0.01423095703125, -0.013834716796875, -0.012556030273437501, -0.010675048828125, -0.00835888671875, -0.0057305908203125, -0.0000562744140625
];

//calc the result for Step 1
step1 = test.reduce(function(pre, cur, index, orgArray){
  if(cur === 0){pre['found'].push({'type':'no-signal','index':index,'value':0});pre['min']={'value':0,'index':0};pre['max']={'value':0,'index':0};return pre;}
  if(pre['max']['value'] < cur) {
    pre['max']={'value':cur,'index':index};
    if(pre['max']['value']>orgArray[index+1]){pre['found'].push({'type':'upwave','index':index,'value':cur})};
  }
  if(pre['min']['value'] > cur) {
    pre['min']={'value':cur,'index':index};
    if(pre['min']['value']<orgArray[index+1]){pre['found'].push({'type':'downwave', 'index':index,'value':cur})};
  }
  if(orgArray[index-1] > 0 && cur < 0){pre['found'].push({'type':'down-cross','index':index});pre['min']={'value':0,'index':0};pre['max']={'value':0,'index':0};}
  if(orgArray[index-1] < 0 && cur > 0){pre['found'].push({'type':'up-cross','index':index});pre['max']={'value':0,'index':0};pre['min']={'value':0,'index':0};}
  return pre
},{'max':{'value':0,'index':0}, 'min':{'value':0,'index':0}, 'found':[]})

//console.log(step1['found']);

//Calc the final result
final = step1['found'].reduce(function(pre, cur, index, orgArray){
  if(cur.type==='downwave' 
    && orgArray[index-1].type==='down-cross' 
    && orgArray[index-2].type==='upwave' ) {
    pre.push({'type':'S', 'index':cur.index, 'value':cur.value});
  }
  if(cur.type==='downwave' 
    && (index+1 < orgArray.length && orgArray[index+1].type==='up-cross' )
    && (index+1 < orgArray.length && orgArray[index+2].type==='upwave') ) {
    pre.push({'type':'Q', 'index':cur.index, 'value':cur.value});
  }
  if(cur.type==='upwave' 
    && orgArray[index-1].type==='up-cross' 
    && (index+1 < orgArray.length && orgArray[index+1].type==='down-cross') ) {
    pre.push({'type':'R', 'index':cur.index, 'value':cur.value});
  }
  return pre;
}, []);
console.log(final);
```

Comment: suppose we have an arrray of 1000 points, and this array has lets say 500 of P,Q,R,S. Does that mean the result variable will only capture those?

Comment: Also, can you please try to make it so that you name the property for each of value found. that way it should be easy to see. Sorry for the hassle, so far youve done a great job. I'm gonna test it

Comment: @Katie, for first question, `result['found']` stores the indexes of all waves and the indexes cross y=zero). so we can calculate out P,Q,R,S from this array. for second question, I am not sure what you mean, each item of `result['found']` has one name to indicate which kind of index it is.

Comment: So found is an array of the properties (i.e. the peaks). So what if we had multiple PQRS in an array, will the `result[found]` store them?

Comment: I drawed one chart in excel, it seems the result matched. so next step will be easy, just calculate out P,Q,R,S from `result['found']`;  for example: `result['found'][1]` is 'upwave', and `result['found'][2]` is 'downcross', so `result['found']` is P.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Made sense!

Comment: @Katie, added one demo to calculate Q,R,R.

Comment: btw, how come can you have S and Q at index 39 with -0.07479357910156251?

Comment: @Katie, because index=30 is **upwave**, index=35 is down-cross, index=39 is downwave, index=42 is up-cross, index=45 is **upwave**. So I think index=39 is one Q for index=30, and is one S for index=45. Probably I put them into wrong category, but that is just one demo, you can adjust the logic by yourself.